# Unable to automount SSHFS with OSXFUSE in fstab

Tags: macos, mount, fstab, sshfs

The line in my `/etc/fstab` file is as follows:

```
sshfs#user@address:/media /Users/acc/Desktop/CODAAMOK     fuse    port=??,reconnect,allow_other,volname=SERVER 0 0
```

The error I'm receiving is as follows:

```
mount: exec /System/Library/Filesystems/fuse.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_fuse for /Users/acc/Desktop/CODAAMOK: No such file or directory
```

The destination directory is indeed valid:

```
CODAAMOKmac:~ acc$ ls /Users/acc/Desktop/
CODAAMOK
```

I'm new to OS X so to my understanding, this doesn't work the way it usually does in the likes of, say, Ubuntu or the like. I'm inclined to believe my issue is the use of `fuse` although I'm not entirely sure. Whilst OSXFUSE version 2.6.4 is installed,  I can't seem to use it in command line when using the term `fuse`. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

**Edit** turns out `fuse.fs` is not present in `/System/Library/Filesystems/`, despite having installed OSXFUSE twice now.

Comment: For other people encountering the same problem, there is a bug in OSXFuse that prevents automounts (fstab on osx is done with automount). It can be worked around fairly easily with a sysctl call. With that I was able to automount sshfs using an autofs direct map. http://superuser.com/a/832916/129020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, see Macfusion. It it is also beneifical to read OSXFUSE's FAQ for their justification for making Macfusion a requirement for SSHFS user space filesystems.

http://macfusionapp.org/

**Edit:** But in the end, I've ended up using ExpanDrive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason you are seeing this error is because you are trying to mount `user@address:/media` to a non-existant directory (`/Users/acc/Desktop/CODAAMOK`) on in your Desktop directory. This is only an assumption since you don't explicitly reveal the contents of your `~/Desktop/` directory.

Comment: Sadly `/Users/acc/Desktop/CODAAMOK` is an existent directory. I will update my question to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

From the [fuse FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/?title=FAQ#Why_doesn.27t_mounting_as_user_work_if_installing_FUSE_from_a_package.3F) :

> **Why doesn't mounting as user work if installing FUSE from a package?**
>
> Distributions often package 'fusermount' without the suid bit, or only
>   executable to the 'fuse' group.
>
> This results in the following message, when trying to mount a
>   filesystem as an unprivileged user:
>
> ```
> fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted
> ```
>
> The simplest solution is to change the mode of 'fusermount':
>
> ```
> chmod 4755 /usr/bin/fusermount
> ```
>
> Note, you may have to do this after each upgrade.

I suggest reading through the entire [Problems section](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/?title=FAQ#Problems) of this FAQ and to verify
all the mentioned points.